# Jquery datepicker multiselection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use the jquery multi date picker. I am using [MultiDatesPicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) plugin.

I need to insert 2 letters in 2 different span tags under each date. For example, there should be A & B text under each date in the calendar.

I tried getting the plugin code in the [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/z86r6vw7/1/) but for some reasons it is not displaying the calendar in fiddle.

```
$('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
   dateFormat: "y-m-d"
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In your jsfiddle you are looking for `.demo .code` but you don't have any element with the `code` class inside the `.demo` element.

Comment: Even without tat, it is not working https://jsfiddle.net/z86r6vw7/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many javascript errors there.

Here is a working snippet you can start with:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <div id="demos">
    <ul id="demos-list">     
      <li class="demo">
        <div id="custom-date-format" class="box"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to append some custom letter to each date. After appending, if I click on any date it is not selecting the date. Any insight? https://jsfiddle.net/543w1pg3/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <div id="demos">
    <ul id="demos-list">                    
      <li class="demo">
        <div id="custom-date-format" class="box"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).